# how can we access different rows of a result set?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a situation where i need to access different rows of result set via JDBC. I'm new to it.

[image]

As seen from picture i need shutoff_valve value as 43 in some variable in my java code. Similarly how to access other node_type values.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some of the Java code that you have tried?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Start with working through some JDBC tutorials first http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html If you ever stucks with a programming problem, ask a concrete question with some concrete code you've as far and the concrete exception you got -if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
        ps = con.prepareStatement(yourSqlHere);
        // optional parameters setting
        ps.setXXX(1, val);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("NODE_TYPE") + ": " + rs.getInt("TOTAL"));
        }
```

Actually, good introduction to low-level JDBC contained in JDK.

Comment: i dont understand this:  ps.setXXX(1, val); can u elaborate

Comment: @Drake JDBC uses different setters for different types of arguments: if you need to specify String argument for your SQL, you use `setString()`, if you need set Long, you use `setLong()`, etc. Again, it's better to refer to JDK tutorial for such a basic stuff.